# Cannot create an object of addressbook.pb.h (which build from protoc)

Tags: c++, xcode, compiler-errors, cocos2d-x

I have spent many hours searching about my problem, but nothing much. I would like to have someone to solve my issue step by step.

The problem is : After building my **addressbook.pro**, I have 2 files (**addressbook.pb.h** and **addressbook.cc**). I have imported them to my project **cocos2dx**. Everything is OK, however, when I try to create my first instance of ***AddressBook class*** ---> **Compile Erro.**

These two images would tell you exact my problem!

[image: My Error Image]

[image: Detail Error]

Please help me, I am really headache with this issue,
Thanks you so much, and also thank to who have a look without comment !

Answer (score 0):

It is a linker error. Perhaps you've forgotten to include the source file **addressbook.cc** in the list of sources.

Comment: OMG, You my god !  . .  . Why am I so stupid T_T, It works ! Thanks Bro so much . . ->.